# Crystal Report is not displaying current records from the database

Tags: crystal-reports

good day! my crystal report is not displaying current or latest records from sql server database. i have to remove and add stored procedure again on the Field Section just to see the current records on the report. is there a way to program it to refresh the records automatically? i'm using c#, sql server and crystal report for my project. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reports files can be saved with data in Crystal Designer. Turn that option off (menu option of ***File, Save Data with Report***).